# Regex to isolate " quote assigned to number

Tags: javascript, abap

I need to isolate and replace double quote assigned to character and not the number.

For example:
I bought 4" plywood from a" store

basically I want to fine and replace " that is assigned to *a* and leave the one that assigned to digit intact, so the outcome should be
I bought 4" plywood from a store

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a free coding service. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: See also [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/4642212) and use regex debuggers like [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/). Particularly, look into lookarounds (lookaheads or lookbehinds) and try something yourself.

Comment: For what programming language is your question, javascript or ABAP? Choose only one of the two tags please.

Answer (score 1):

Try to match a `char + "` and to replace it in string (removing `"`):

```js
let str = "I bought 4\" plywood from a\" store";
let match = str.match(/([A-Za-z]")/i);
let res = str.replace(/([A-Za-z]")/i, match[0].replace("\"", ""));
console.log(res);
```